# Dataset: language audio clips and country labels

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, bigdata, data, audio-recognition

I'm looking for a dataset containing audio clips of different languages from around the world, including a label indicating which country the clip comes from.

Does such a dataset exist? Or is there an easy way to hack one together?

Comment: There is a good chance of finding better responses from opendata SE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Topcoder hosted competition for identifying spoken languages. They released a database containing 176 languages. The datasets and the related resources can be found [here](https://community.topcoder.com/longcontest/?module=ViewProblemStatement&rd=16555&compid=49304).